# Не отрабатывает метод `click` во вьюшке ember.js

Tags: ember.js, javascript

Собственно пытаюсь сделать модальное окно при помощи ember.js. При клике на `<a href="#" class="close">×</a>` не срабатывает метод `App.Modal.click`. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так я делаю?

```
App.Modal = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div'
    , classNames: ['modal','w740']
    , defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view view.heading}}<a href="#" class="close">×</a>{{{view view.body}}}')
    , title: null
    , heading: Ember.View.extend({
        tagName: 'h3',
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.parentView.title}}')
    })
    , content: null
    , body: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{{view.parentView.content}}}')
    })
    , click: function(event) {
        console.log('method::winModal::click', event);
    }
    , keyPress: function(event) {
        console.log('method::winModal::keyPress', event);
    }
});
```

Кусочек кода реализации вьюшки. Если нужно что то еще - добавлю. Спасибо.

Касяк найден. Я вьшку вставлял вне `App.rootElement`, из-за чего все `action` не обрабатывались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу где вы вешаете обработчик на ссылку. Попробуйте так:

```
<a href="#" class="close" {{action "click"}} >×</a>
```

Приведите полный код вьюхи и контроллера. Где создаются объекты view. можете исходники залить на `sendspace.com` и кинуть ссылку.